# Necesito ayuda con una transformacion en css

Tags: css

Amigo tengo una pregunta que transformacion o transicion sirve para hacer que un contenedor se vea que esta saliendo de la pantalla osea que cuando se pase el puntero se leventa sobre si mismo, me podrian decir el nombre porfavor.

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas es mejor hacerlas por el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol)

Comment: No tengo la reputacion suficiente amigo

Comment: bueno, el evento se llama hover, y sobre ese evento puedes aumentar el widht y height o cualquier propiedad de un elemento, la que tu quieras. [Ver hover](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Comment: Si bro yo se eso, pero crei que asi como css tiene sus transformaciones tendria una de esas que haria eso sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso se puede utilizar la propiedad `transition` para dar un efecto suave y al hover un `transform: scale()` para aumentar el tamaño del elemento.

```css
.elemento {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.elemento:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="elemento"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo!..